# TDengine alert rule can not run

Tags: grafana, alert, tdengine

My TDengine graph works fine, but the alert rule can not run. I got this detailed error message "tsdb.HandleRequest() error Could not find executor for data source type: tdengine-datasource".

version info：
system 14.04.1-Ubuntu,
grafana v7.3.5,
grafanaplugin 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Use grafnaplugin 3.1.4, you can download it from https://github.com/taosdata/grafanaplugin/releases/tag/v3.1.4 .
Then follow the installation instructions in README https://github.com/taosdata/grafanaplugin#installation .

Join the community here in [discord](https://discord.gg/VZdSuUg4pS?utm_source=website&utm_medium=widget&utm_campaign=channel&utm_id=discord) for help.

Comment: OK. Let me try it.